# How do I generate ActionLink from code behind in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On `HomeController.cs` code :

```
 if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var profile = Profile.GetProfile(User.Identity.Name);
                ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome " + profile.FirstName + "!";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to myblog.";
                ViewData["RegisterLink"] = "please register <%:Html.ActionLink('Register', 'Register', 'Account')%>.";
            }
```

If user is not logged in it should have to show 
welcome to myblog and please register (it must be actionlink)

and on index.aspx inside Content code is:

```
  <%:  ViewData["RegisterLink"] %>
```

But I'm failed to generate ActionLink please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to tackle what you want, I prefer the strongly typed view approach but you could try the following:

```
ViewData["RegisterLink"] = "true";
```

Then inside your View, if `RegisterLink` is true, show the ActionLink().

Comment: where I need to put 
"To know more about Mavericks System register yourself <%:Html.ActionLink('Register', 'Register', 'Account')%>" ?

Comment: What is happening here is that you are setting ViewData[] variables inside your ActionResult which happens to be considered as *Server-Side Code*. Once these variables are set, your View() is then called. Since the ViewData[] variables has been set *before* the View actually gets displayed, you can access (and verify) the values inside those variables. So…what this means is that you can, test for the following: if(ViewData[“RegisterLink”] == “true”)…show your Html.ActionLink(…). Keep in mind this code is *inside* your View not in the Controller.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to generate anchor from code

```
TagBuilder linkBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
linkBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", Url.Action("Register", "Account"));
linkBuilder.SetInnerText("Please Register");
ViewData["RegisterLink"] = linkBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to avoid using ViewData and use a strongly typed ViewModel to handle this.

My ViewModel will be like this

```
public class LoggedInUserViewModel : 
{

  public bool IsValid { set;get;}
  public string DisplayName { set;get;}

}
```

in the controller, check the user is authenticated, and set the properties of the ViewModel object and pass the ViewModel object to the View

```
LoggedInUserViewModel objVM=new LoggedInUserViewModel();
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   objVM.IsValid=true;
   objVm.DisplayName="Name from your user entity"

}
return View(objVm);
```

and in the View

```
 @if(Model.IsValid) 
 {
   @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users")
 }
 else
 {
  Welcome @Model.DisplayName
   @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Profile", "Users")
 }
```